# How do I selecting a date range (like onClick but drag/select)

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'd like to rewrite [vizwit](http://vizwit.io) using Chart.js, and I'm having a hard time figuring out how to get the date/time chart interaction to work. If you try selecting a date range on [this demo](http://vizw.it/?gist=51db593dc0537d1a3f05), you'll see that it filters the other charts. How do I get Chart.js to let me select a range like that on its time scale chart? It seems like by default it only lets me click on a specific date point.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Building on @jordanwillis's and your answers, you can easily achieve anything you want, by placing another canvas on top on your chart.
Just add `pointer-events:none` to it's style to make sure it doesn't intefere with the chart's events.
No need to use the annotations plugin.
For example (in this example `canvas` is the original chart canvas and `overlay` is your new canvas placed on top):

```js
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderWidth: 1
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderWidth: 1
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          reverse: false
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}

var canvas = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, options);
var overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');
var startIndex = 0;
overlay.width = canvas.width;
overlay.height = canvas.height;
var selectionContext = overlay.getContext('2d');
var selectionRect = {
  w: 0,
  startX: 0,
  startY: 0
};
var drag = false;
canvas.addEventListener('pointerdown', evt => {
  const points = chart.getElementsAtEventForMode(evt, 'index', {
    intersect: false
  });
  startIndex = points[0]._index;
  const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  selectionRect.startX = evt.clientX - rect.left;
  selectionRect.startY = chart.chartArea.top;
  drag = true;
  // save points[0]._index for filtering
});
canvas.addEventListener('pointermove', evt => {

  const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  if (drag) {
    const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    selectionRect.w = (evt.clientX - rect.left) - selectionRect.startX;
    selectionContext.globalAlpha = 0.5;
    selectionContext.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    selectionContext.fillRect(selectionRect.startX,
      selectionRect.startY,
      selectionRect.w,
      chart.chartArea.bottom - chart.chartArea.top);
  } else {
    selectionContext.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    var x = evt.clientX - rect.left;
    if (x > chart.chartArea.left) {
      selectionContext.fillRect(x,
        chart.chartArea.top,
        1,
        chart.chartArea.bottom - chart.chartArea.top);
    }
  }
});
canvas.addEventListener('pointerup', evt => {

  const points = chart.getElementsAtEventForMode(evt, 'index', {
    intersect: false
  });
  drag = false;
  console.log('implement filter between ' + options.data.labels[startIndex] + ' and ' + options.data.labels[points[0]._index]);  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.0/Chart.js"></script>

<body>
  <canvas id="overlay" width="600" height="400" style="position:absolute;pointer-events:none;"></canvas>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
</body>
```

Notice we're basing our events and coordinates on the original canvas, but we draw on the overlay. This way we don't mess the chart's functionality.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The example looks spot on.

Comment: This is really great answer, but for me its really laggy. I think window.requestAnimationFrame() should be used here somehow

Comment: Hey how do I keep the selected rectangle visible at-least till I click anywhere else. Right now as soon as I release the mouse the selected part disappears

Comment: hi @ShubhamCSE, notice that we register pointerup event and set drag to false. Then in pointermove event we clear the rectangle. You can add your logic there, not to clear it.

Answer (score 7):

For all of you interested in Jony Adamits solution, I created a ChartJs plugin based on his implementation. Additionaly I fixed some minor issues in regard to resizing the chart and detection of the selected data points.

Feel free to use it or to create a plugin github repo for it.

#### Installation

```js
import "chart.js";
import {Chart} from 'chart.js';
import {ChartJsPluginRangeSelect} from "./chartjs-plugin-range-select";

Chart.pluginService.register(new ChartJsPluginRangeSelect());
```

#### Configuration

```js
let chartOptions = rangeSelect: {
  onSelectionChanged: (result: Array<Array<any>>) => {
    console.log(result);
  }
}
```

#### Plugin Code

```js
import {Chart, ChartSize, PluginServiceGlobalRegistration, PluginServiceRegistrationOptions} from "chart.js";

interface ChartJsPluginRangeSelectExtendedOptions {
  rangeSelect?: RangeSelectOptions;
}

interface RangeSelectOptions {
  onSelectionChanged?: (filteredDataSets: Array<Array<any>>) => void;
  fillColor?: string | CanvasGradient | CanvasPattern;
  cursorColor?: string | CanvasGradient | CanvasPattern;
  cursorWidth?: number;
  state?: RangeSelectState;
}

interface RangeSelectState {
  canvas: HTMLCanvasElement;
}

interface ActiveSelection {
  x: number;
  w: number;
}

export class ChartJsPluginRangeSelect implements PluginServiceRegistrationOptions, PluginServiceGlobalRegistration {
  public id = 'rangeSelect';

  beforeInit(chartInstance: Chart, options?: any) {
    const opts = (chartInstance.config.options as ChartJsPluginRangeSelectExtendedOptions);
    if (opts.rangeSelect) {
      const canvas = this.createOverlayCanvas(chartInstance);
      opts.rangeSelect = Object.assign({}, opts.rangeSelect, {state: {canvas: canvas}});
      chartInstance.canvas.parentElement.prepend(canvas);
    }
  }

  resize(chartInstance: Chart, newChartSize: ChartSize, options?: any) {
    const rangeSelectOptions = (chartInstance.config.options as ChartJsPluginRangeSelectExtendedOptions).rangeSelect;
    if (rangeSelectOptions) {
      rangeSelectOptions.state.canvas.width = newChartSize.width;
      rangeSelectOptions.state.canvas.height = newChartSize.height;
    }
  }

  destroy(chartInstance: Chart) {
    const rangeSelectOptions = (chartInstance.config.options as ChartJsPluginRangeSelectExtendedOptions).rangeSelect;
    if (rangeSelectOptions) {
      rangeSelectOptions.state.canvas.remove();
      delete rangeSelectOptions.state;
    }
  }

  private createOverlayCanvas(chart: Chart): HTMLCanvasElement {
    const rangeSelectOptions = (chart.config.options as ChartJsPluginRangeSelectExtendedOptions).rangeSelect;
    const overlay = this.createOverlayHtmlCanvasElement(chart);
    const ctx = overlay.getContext('2d');

    let selection: ActiveSelection = {x: 0, w: 0};
    let isDragging = false;

    chart.canvas.addEventListener('pointerdown', evt => {
      const rect = chart.canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
      selection.x = this.getXInChartArea(evt.clientX - rect.left, chart);
      isDragging = true;
    });

    chart.canvas.addEventListener('pointerleave', evt => {
      if (!isDragging) {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, overlay.width, overlay.height);
      }
    });

    chart.canvas.addEventListener('pointermove', evt => {
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, chart.canvas.width, chart.canvas.height);

      const chartContentRect = chart.canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
      const currentX = this.getXInChartArea(evt.clientX - chartContentRect.left, chart);
      if (isDragging) {
        selection.w = currentX - selection.x;
        ctx.fillStyle = rangeSelectOptions.fillColor || '#00000044';
        ctx.fillRect(selection.x, chart.chartArea.top, selection.w, chart.chartArea.bottom - chart.chartArea.top);
      } else {
        const cursorWidth = rangeSelectOptions.cursorWidth || 1;
        ctx.fillStyle = rangeSelectOptions.cursorColor || '#00000088';
        ctx.fillRect(currentX, chart.chartArea.top, cursorWidth, chart.chartArea.bottom - chart.chartArea.top);
      }
    });

    chart.canvas.addEventListener('pointerup', evt => {
      const onSelectionChanged = rangeSelectOptions.onSelectionChanged;
      if (onSelectionChanged) {
        onSelectionChanged(this.getDataSetDataInSelection(selection, chart));
      }
      selection = {w: 0, x: 0};
      isDragging = false;
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, overlay.width, overlay.height);
    });
    return overlay;
  }

  private createOverlayHtmlCanvasElement(chartInstance: Chart): HTMLCanvasElement {
    const overlay = document.createElement('canvas');
    overlay.style.position = 'absolute';
    overlay.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
    overlay.width = chartInstance.canvas.width;
    overlay.height = chartInstance.canvas.height;
    return overlay;
  }

  private getXInChartArea(val: number, chartInstance: Chart) {
    return Math.min(Math.max(val, chartInstance.chartArea.left), chartInstance.chartArea.right);
  }

  private getDataSetDataInSelection(selection: ActiveSelection, chartInstance: Chart): Array<any> {
    const result = [];
    const xMin = Math.min(selection.x, selection.x + selection.w);
    const xMax = Math.max(selection.x, selection.x + selection.w);
    for (let i = 0; i < chartInstance.data.datasets.length; i++) {
      result[i] = chartInstance.getDatasetMeta(i)
        .data
        .filter(data => xMin <= data._model.x && xMax >= data._model.x)
        .map(data => chartInstance.data.datasets[i].data[data._index]);
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

Comment: Kali
You have not mentioned that this is in TypeScript.
The main code too uses TS stuff Array<Array<any>>

Please  give a working example in jsfiddle eliminating all TS 
After all we are dealing with chart.js not chart.ts

I can sense your code may work hence please do help.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, nothing like this is built into chart.js.  You would have to implement your own event hooks and handlers that would render a highlighted section on a chart and then use the `.getElementsAtEvent(e)` prototype method to figure out what data has been highlighted.  Even these hooks that are built in may not be enough to implement what you are wanting.

Event hook options are:

- Add event handlers on the canvas element itself (see example below)

  ```
  canvas.onclick = function(evt){
      var activePoints = myLineChart.getElementsAtEvent(evt);
      // => activePoints is an array of points on the canvas that are at the same position as the click event.
  };
  ```
- Add event handler on the chart.js chart object using the `onClick` config option ([explained here](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#chart-configuration-common-chart-configuration)).
- Extend some of the core charts event hooks and add your own.  (see [here](https://chartjs.gitbooks.io/proposals/content/Platform.html) for some guidance).

Assuming this approach works, then you could then filter your original chart data array accordingly (in the underlying chart.js object) and call the `.update()` prototype method to paint a new chart.

Answer (score 3):

The people who made ChartJS also made a plugin called [chartjs-plugin-zoom](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-zoom). To install the plugin type:

```
npm install chartjs-plugin-zoom.
```

Implement:

```
import { Chart } from 'chart.js';
import zoomPlugin from 'chartjs-plugin-zoom';

Chart.register(zoomPlugin);
```

To add zooming functionality by dragging, add this to the chart configuration:

```
options: {
        plugins: {
          zoom: {
            pan: {
              enabled: true,
              mode: 'x',
              modifierKey: 'ctrl',
            },
            zoom: {
              drag: {
                enabled: true
              },
              mode: 'x'
            }
          }
        }
     }
```

A more thorough installation and use tutorial can be found [here](https://www.chartjs.org/chartjs-plugin-zoom/latest/).
Instructions on how to implement zooming functionality can be found [here](https://www.chartjs.org/chartjs-plugin-zoom/latest/samples/drag/category.html).

Answer (score 1):

Update a few months later based on @jordanwillis' answer: I've got the beginnings of range selection.

```
canvas.onpointerdown = function (evt) {
  clearAnnotations()
  const points = chart.getElementsAtEventForMode(evt, 'index', { intersect: false })
  const label = chart.data.labels[points[0]._index]
  addAnnotation(label)
}

canvas.onpointerup = function (evt) {
  const points = chart.getElementsAtEventForMode(evt, 'index', { intersect: false })
  const label = chart.data.labels[points[0]._index]
  addAnnotation(label)
}

function clearAnnotations () {
  if (chart.options.annotation) {
    chart.options.annotation.annotations = []
  }
}

function addAnnotation (label) {
  const annotation = {
    scaleID: 'x-axis-0',
    type: 'line',
    mode: 'vertical',
    value: label,
    borderColor: 'red'
  }
  chart.options.annotation = chart.options.annotation || {}
  chart.options.annotation.annotations = chart.options.annotation.annotations || []
  chart.options.annotation.annotations.push(annotation)
  chart.update()
}
```

Still need to figure out how to show a visual hover indicator as in the demo linked in the question, but it's a start.