# Width and height attribute of canvas is returning 0 in Vue JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I'm using Vue JS and I have 2 canvases in my component (I'm trying to recreate [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42855738/how-do-i-selecting-a-date-range-like-onclick-but-drag-select)).

Template part of component:

```
<template>
    <div class="d-flex flex-column">
        <div class="d-flex flex-column" style="height: 300px;">
            <canvas ref="overlay" id="overlay" style="position: absolute; pointer-events: none"></canvas>
            <canvas ref="canvas" :id="canvasId"></canvas>
        </div>
        <vue-slider @drag-end="selectRange" class="w-100 mb-3 mx-3 p-0 pr-3" ref="slider" v-model="sliderValue" v-bind="sliderOptions"></vue-slider>
    </div>
</template>
```

Script part of component:

```
<script>
    import chartjs from "chart.js";
    import vueSlider from "vue-slider-component";
    import {Line} from "vue-chartjs";

    const props = {
        dataset: {
            type: Array,
            required: true
        },
        index: {
            type: Number,
            required: true
        },
        sliderShow: {
            type: Boolean,
            required: true
        }
    };

    export default {
        components: { vueSlider },
        extends: Line,
        name: "rhythmogram",
        props,
        data() {
            return {
                canvasId: "",
                sliderValue: [],
                sliderOptions: {
                    tooltip: "hover",
                    "tooltip-dir": "bottom",
                    overlapFormatter: "{value1} - {value2}",
                    tooltipStyle: {
                        "borderRadius": "0px"
                    },
                    useKeyboard: true,
                    data: []
                },
                chartData: [],
                xLabels: []
            };
        },
        mounted() {
            this.canvasId = `areachart${this.index}`;

            this.$nextTick(() => {

                // ... 
                // filling this.chartData and this.xLabels
                // ...

                this.renderChart({
                    labels: this.xLabels,
                    datasets: [{
                        label: this.name,
                        data: this.chartData
                    }]
                }, {
                    maintainAspectRatio: false,
                    elements: {
                        line: {
                            tension: 0.2,
                            borderWidth: 1,
                            borderColor: "rgba(24, 81, 154, .95)",
                            backgroundColor: "rgba(24, 81, 154, .5)"
                        },
                        point: {
                            pointStyle: "circle",
                            radius: 0
                        }
                    },
                    tooltips: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    legend: {
                        display: false
                    },
                    scales: {
                        yAxes: [{
                            ticks: {
                                beginAtZero: true,
                                min: minValueToDisplay,
                                max: maxValueToDisplay
                            }
                        }],
                        xAxes: [{
                            ticks: {
                                stepSize: 10
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                });

                // Overlay
                var canvas = this.$refs.canvas;
                var overlay = this.$refs.overlay;
                var chart = this._data._chart;

                var startIndex = 0;
                var endIndex = 0;

                overlay.width = canvas.width;
                overlay.height = canvas.height;

                console.log(canvas); //this returns the correct element with width and height > 0
                console.log("Width:\t" + canvas.width); //this returns 0
                console.log("Height:\t" + canvas.height); // this returns 0

                var selectionContext = overlay.getContext('2d');
                var selectionRect = {
                    w: 0,
                    startX: 0,
                    startY: 0
                };
                var drag = false;
                canvas.addEventListener('pointerdown', evt => {
                    const points = chart.getElementsAtEventForMode(evt, 'index', {
                        intersect: false
                    });
                    startIndex = points[0]._index;
                    const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
                    selectionRect.startX = evt.clientX - rect.left;
                    selectionRect.startY = chart.chartArea.top;
                    drag = true;
                });

                canvas.addEventListener('pointermove', evt => {
                    const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
                    if (drag) {
                        const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
                        selectionRect.w = (evt.clientX - rect.left) - selectionRect.startX;
                        selectionContext.globalAlpha = 0.5;
                        selectionContext.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                        selectionContext.fillRect(selectionRect.startX, selectionRect.startY, selectionRect.w, chart.chartArea.bottom -
                            chart.chartArea.top);
                    } else {
                        selectionContext.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.widht, canvas.height);
                        var x = evt.clientX - rect.left;
                        if (x > chart.chartArea.left) {
                            selectionContext.fillRect(x, chart.chartArea.top, 1, chart.chartArea.bottom - chart.chartArea.top);
                        }
                    }
                });

                canvas.addEventListener('pointerup', evt => {
                    const points = chart.getElementsAtEventForMode(evt, 'index', {
                        intersect: false
                    });
                    drag = false;
                    console.log('selected: ' + this.sliderOptions.data[startIndex] + ', ' + this.sliderOptions.data[points[0]._index]);
                });

            });
        },
        methods: {
            selectRange() {
                // stuff
            }
        },
        watch: {
            sliderShow(val) {
                // stuff
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

I have commented the lines where it returns 0 for the `width` and `height`.
I found out that it works when I give my canvas a set `width` and `height` as an HTML attribute and set the ChartJS chart to `responsive: false` in its options.

But I need a responsive chart. And in the answer of the stackoverflow post I linked above it is working with a responsive chart.

I also tried getting the element with pure JS and jQuery to see if thats the culprit but to no avail.

Any help is appreciated. If any information is missing please tell me.

Comment: <canvas ref="canvas" :id="canvasId"></canvas> unless it is vue.js specific it supposed to be <canvas ref="canvas" id="canvasId"></canvas>

Comment: Can u add [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @spectatorx it is Vue specific